# How to make search of list with none english letters?

Tags: reactjs, django, search, utf-8

I am making e-commerce website on ( React.js - client )and ( Python Django - client ). I am trying to make a search feature for list of all products and the queries are none-english. Whenever I try to search, my none-english query gets into hell knows what. For example I input query "текст" and it turns to / search / %D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82. Expected: / search / текст.
[image: How my requests go on client side..]

And of course my api cannot find any product with this query..

```
@api_view(["GET"]) 
def searchData(request, q):
  searchedData = Product.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=q))
  data = ProductSerializer(searchedData, many=True).data
  return Response(data)
```

This is my search view.

```
path('search/<str:q>/', views.searchData)
```

This is my path.

I hope for any kind of help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82` in fact is `текст`, but is url encoded, you have to decode it.
You can verify this on this page https://www.urldecoder.io/